# Preencher Select com dados do Banco

Tags: php, javascript

Como Atualizar um input select com informações vindo do Banco de Dados e ainda aprensetar as opções para a pessoa escolher para atualizar?

```
$id=filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$result="SELECT * FROM banco WHERE id='$id' ";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$result);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

 <select name="motorista"         id="motorista"       placeholder="MOTORISTA" autocomplete="off"   >      
         <?php echo '<option value="'.$row_cat_post['id'].'">'.$motorista.'</option>';?>
</select><br>
```

Dessa forma ele tras apenas o resultado armazenado. N apresenta as opções primarias que fizeram o cadastro.
Lembrando que uso chave estrangeira, então o que é salvo é a chave que relaciona ao banco secundario e não o nome do produto propriamente dito.

Comment: Precisa de um loop

Answer (score 0):

```
//vou consider que você já efetuou o inicio do codigo php e inclui a conexão com o banco atravez do "includ_once"

$id=filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$result="SELECT * FROM banco WHERE id='$id' ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

//Deve ser inserido um laço de repetição para a cada linha do seu banco ele imprimir o resultado esperado. Neste caso vamos utilizar o while.
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo '<select name="motorista" id="motorista" placeholder="MOTORISTA" autocomplete="off">';
      echo '<option value="'.$row_cat_post['id'].'">'.$motorista.'</option>';
   echo '</select><br>';
}
```